# How do I send texbox and attachement to webmethod using jquery ajax call?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to send textbox and input file data to my webmethod. I have been googling for quite sometime now but still not sure how I can achieve this:

**Jquery/AJAX CALL:**

```
 var dataToSend = new FormData();           
 dataToSend.append('file',  document.getElementById("myFile").value);
 dataToSend.append('text',  document.getElementById("biddername").value);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "SupplierMaster.aspx/RegisterSupplier",
                data: dataToSend,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                dataType: false,
                async: true,
                success: function (data, status) {
                    console.log("CallWM");
                    alert(data.d);
                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                }
            });

        }
```

**WebMethod:**

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string RegisterSupplier(HttpPostedFile file, string biddername)
    {

        return "a";
    }
```

It seems that I am unable to invoke webmethod.

**EDIT1(as suggested by Kashif):**

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "SupplierMaster.aspx/RegisterSupplier",
                data: "{'file' : " + document.getElementById("myFile").value + ",'biddername':" + document.getElementById("txtsuppliername").value + "}",
                async: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data, status) {
                    console.log("CallWM");
                    alert(data.d);
                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                }
            });


[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod] 
    public static string RegisterSupplier(HttpPostedFile file, string biddername)
    {

        return "a";
    }
```

*

Comment: First of all the `url` you are trying to call in ajax is `SupplierMaster.aspx/RegisterSupplier` and but you do not have method with name `RegisterSupplier` instead you are showing us method with name `SubmitBid`??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao sorry, i wrote the webmethod instead of copy pasting. I have updated the question but the problem still persists

Comment: Did you try putting break point?? Is it hitting that webmethod??

Comment: yeah i have been trying that, but no its not hitting that webmethod

Comment: try setting `datatype` to `json` like `dataType: "json",`

Comment: it was json initially but someone pointed out that i cant send files using dataType: "json"

Comment: You can send!! Check the ajax call in the question **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917058/file-upload-through-ajax-does-not-append-file-in-request-in-mvc)** and answer given..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao still no luck

Comment: give me a moment!! Let me try re-creating your problem!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao yes sure. :)

Comment: your webmethod is in same `cs` page or different??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao its in .cs file of same webform

Comment: Huge difference what i have suggested and what you tried

Comment: @Kashif I have edited it now. I have tried what I posted and what you have suggested both. See my question now.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why do you use `document.getElementById("myFile").value` and not the much shorter and concise `$("#myFile").val()`?

Comment: @TsahiAsher yes you are right. I might change it to $("#myFile").val() but i dont think that would solve the problem at hand.

Comment: I have changed File to base64 string. try now with   my updated code

Comment: I did. Its not hitting webmethod

Comment: @Arbaaz no it won't, I was just wondering as a side note.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this.** Edited one.  Here i am converting file to base64 with Btoa().

```
dataToSend: "{'file' : " + btoa(document.getElementById("myFile").value)+ ",'biddername':" +  document.getElementById("biddername").value+ "}",

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "YourWebMethodClassName.aspx/SubmitBid",
                data: dataToSend,
                async: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",           
                success: function (data, status) {
                    console.log("CallWM");
                    alert(data.d);
                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                }
            });

        }
```

C#-- Edit code

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string RegisterSupplier(string file, string biddername)
    {
// Write here logic to convert Base64 to file.

        return "a";
    }
```

Comment: [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]   add this on c# method

Comment: I have updated my question again with your suggestion. Its still not hitting webmethod

Comment: Edit this again.  i did not suggest .  processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                dataType: false,

Comment: Is this working at your end? Because it isnt at mine.

Comment: Have you changed  HttpPostedFile  to string in  RegisterSupplier?

Comment: Have you changed file to Base64 in java script ?

Comment: Yes I am sure I did exactly as you posted. Are you sure this should work? have you tested this? Because I just tried this and it does not work.

Comment: I was able to hit the webmethod by using JSON stringify but it seems that it only sends the name of the file.

Comment: Debug in javascript and see are you geteting data there

Comment: This will never work. You are encoding the file *name* (to the extent it is available at all, but that's another issue), and not the file *content*, and then you are sending it to the server. For that you don't need Base64.

Answer (score 0):

You can't AJAX post the content of a file. You have to POST a form with the file. You should search how to post a form with a file input to a web method.