# jQuery sending file with ajax to MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send a file using jQuery to my MVC controller but the action keeps receiving a null HttpPostedFileBase parameter.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="upload" value="Submit"/>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('#upload').click(function () {

        var data = new FormData($('#file')[0].files[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Upload", "Home")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    // file = null
}
```

new FormData($('#file')[0].files[0]):

```
__proto__: FormData
```

$('#file')[0].files[0]:

```
lastModified: 1445429215528
lastModifiedDate: Wed Oct 21 2015 14:06:55 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)
name: "Google_Chrome_logo_2011.jpg"
size: 5506
type: "image/jpg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
```

I pretty much copied the code from other examples that I found on the internet but somehow it is just not working.

Comment: Well you can get some help from **[this question and answer mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917058/file-upload-through-ajax-does-not-append-file-in-request-in-mvc)**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
{
   foreach (string file in Request.Files)
   {
      var _file = Request.Files[file];
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
var $file = document.getElementById('file'),
    $formData = new FormData();

if ($file.files.length > 0) {
   for (var i = 0; i < $file.files.length; i++) {
      $formData.append('file-' + i, $file.files[i]);
   }
}

$.ajax({
   url: '/home/upload',
   type: 'POST',
   data: $formData,
   dataType: 'json',
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   success: function ($data) {

   }
 });
```

Comment: Just tested it and Count result is 0

Comment: Is it possible with out FormData

Answer (score 0):

This is my Solution

```
var formData = new FormData();
var files = $('input[type=file]');
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
if (files[i].value == "" || files[i].value == null) {
 return false;
}
else {
 formData.append(files[i].name, files[i].files[0]);
}
}
var formSerializeArray = $("#Form").serializeArray();
for (var i = 0; i < formSerializeArray.length; i++) {
  formData.append(formSerializeArray[i].name, formSerializeArray[i].value)
}
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 data: formData,
 contentType: false,
 processData: false,
 cache: false,
 url: '/Controller/Action',
 success: function (response) {
 if (response.Success == true) {
    return true;
 }
 else {
    return false;
 }
 },
 error: function () {
   return false;
 },
 failure: function () {
   return false;
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send file to the controller you can use this approach:

```
var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("YOUR_KEY", $("#ID_OF_Input_Type_File").prop('files')[0]);
    
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/UploadFile',
        type: "POST",
        data: formdata,
        contentType: false, // Not to set any content header  
        processData: false, // Not to process data
        success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
        error: function (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
});
```

And your Controller will look like this:

```
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase YOUR_KEY)
{   
     // your file operations here....
     return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```